# how to create a hot-key to control a volume app

Tags: application-development, system-settings

I was wonder if there is a way to create a hot-key to control PulseAudio app? Due to YouTube being in full screen and adjusting down the volume.

Comment: Are you using XFCE, or can add customizable keyboard shortcuts fairly easily? And you know that YouTube should accept the arrow up & down buttons to change it's volume? Or does YouTube change your desktop's "master" volume somehow?

Comment: changes the desktop's master volume.

Comment: yes control volume

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to control volume up and down with a key combination.

try adding these entries to All Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts->Custom shortcuts by clicking +:

Volume down: amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-

Volume up: amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+

Assign the key combination you want by clicking on the above two entries.

This will be helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-shortcuts-set.html

Comment: I'm not seeing how to add the Volume up and down options to the app I just added.

Comment: Ended up putting enters in Global Shortcuts for the Launch PulseAudio as shift + <left arror> then in Custom Shortcuts added PulseAudio then under PulseAudio add New --> Global Shortcut --> Command/URL = Volume up: amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+ , and Volume down: amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-

Comment: works ok but does stop volume from moving unless PulseAudio is open and volume has been manually adjusted the shortcuts don't work